# SharePoint JavaScript API for Workflow throws an error

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-jsom

I am trying to access information about running workflows in a SharePoint list but I am running into problems with the workflow services JSOM library. I am using the workflow services just like every example I can find, see code below:

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var servicesManager = SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(context, web);
var instanceService = servicesManager.getWorkflowInstanceService();
```

While executing the code, the last line in the above snippet throws an exception

> TypeError: this.get_context is not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Propbaly this error occurs since one of the specified files from SharePoint JavaScript library has not been loaded.

- `SP.js`
- `SP.Runtime.js`
- `SP.WorkflowServices.js`

To ensure that the specified file(s) has been loaded you could consider the following approach:

```
SP.SOD.registerSod('SP.ClientContext', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('sp.js'));
SP.SOD.registerSod('SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('SP.WorkflowServices.js'));
SP.SOD.loadMultiple(['SP.ClientContext', 'SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager'], function(){

    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var workflowServicesManager = SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(ctx, ctx.get_web()); 
    var workflowSubscriptionService = workflowServicesManager.getWorkflowSubscriptionService();                
    //...    

});
```

> [SP.SOD.loadMultiple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff409592%28v=office.14%29.aspx) function is intended for loading on demand scripts
>   which in turn is a part of SharePoint JavaScript Library.
>   Alternatively you could utilize [jQuery.getScript()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) from jQuery
>   library.

Comment: I thought about that as well and do not believe that to be the case. I have taken a different approach by using the ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded methods so that the above code has been wrapped with:
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
            ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
                <code here/>
            }, "sp.workflowservices.js");
        }, "sp.runtime.js");
    }, "sp.js");

I'll will modify the code to try the SOD approach and see if makes a difference though.

Answer (score 1):

@VadimGremyachev, I tried using your code example and I then got a TypeError related to SP.Utilities.  I guess SP.Utilities is part of sp.js so it couldn't be used to load itself.  The only way in which I was able to get it working correctly was to use both the SOD and ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded methods. I don't know if this is a nuance of using this using client-side rendering to override a list view or just bad timing of script loading.  The code that works is as follows:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
        SP.SOD.registerSod('SP.ClientContext', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('sp.js'));
        SP.SOD.registerSod('SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('SP.WorkflowServices.js'));
        SP.SOD.loadMultiple(['SP.ClientContext', 'SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager'], function () {
            var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var web = context.get_web();
            var servicesManager = SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(context, web);
            var instanceService = servicesManager.getWorkflowInstanceService();
        });
    }, "sp.js");
}, "sp.runtime.js");`
```

Comment: This worked for me. I did not try @vadim-gremyachev answer because I've been fighting with this 2013 script on demand crap for three days. The other answer might work but I am so, so, so, so, so done. Thank you travis-l